# Lift and shift SSIS packages to ADF

Tags: ssis, azure-data-factory

I am working on lift and shift SSIS packages through ADF. Setup have been done properly but when I trigger the activity in ADF, I see this error "Package execution failed. For more details, select the output of your activity run on the same row". How to resolve this error?

Comment: Can you share the exact and complete error message that you see and more details on how you have configured self-hosted Integration runtime ?

Comment: please share few snips if convenient and also mention if you are following any documentation in particular

Comment: We have configured Self hosted integration runtime with SSISDB and Vnet enabled.

Comment: If the answer was helpful , You can [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), ( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.) so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem

Answer (score 0):

Going through the official MS docs, I can see the below error documented. Can you try as suggested.

[Error message: "Staging task failed. TaskStatus: Failed, ErrorCode: 2906, ErrorMessage: Package execution failed. For more details, select the output of your activity run on the same row., Output: {"OperationErrorMessages": "4/14/2021 7:10:35 AM +00:00 : = Failed to start Named pipe proxy... "](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/ssis-integration-runtime-ssis-activity-faq#error-message---staging-task-failed--taskstatus--failed--errorcode--2906--errormessage--package-execution-failed--for-more-details--select-the-output-of-your-activity-run-on-the-same-row---output----operationerrormessages----4-14-2021-7-10-35-am--00-00-----failed-to-start-named-pipe-proxy-----)

> Check if security policies are correctly assigned to the account
> running self-hosted IR service. If Windows authentication is used on
> Execute SSIS Package activity or the execution credential is set in
> SSIS catalog (SSISDB), the same security policies must be assigned to
> the Windows account used. More detail can be found at [Configure
> Self-Hosted IR as a proxy for Azure-SSIS IR in
> ADF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/self-hosted-integration-runtime-proxy-ssis#enable-windows-authentication-for-on-premises-tasks)